# How do you say "spread" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario, se, verbo-pronominal

Like in the sentence:

> The poison spread out all over her body.
>
> El veneno .... por todo su cuerpo.

Comment: Hola Gina. Has realizado ya unas cuantas preguntas en [spanish.se] y ya sería necesario que siguieras más y mejor las indicaciones dadas en [ask]. [Edit]a utilizando formato, mostrando lo que intentaste... y estoy convencido de que recibirás muy buenas y útiles respuestas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a dictionary in order to translate `spread`. I just [used wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=spread) and got a couple of decent proposals, like *extenderse* and *difundirse*.

The different connotations between all these verbs (`extender`, `propagar`, `difundir`) could be another question or an important part for this question, but you can see how the dictionary/translator already suggests `propagar` as the favored use with "illness" (since the connotation is *propagate* instead of *extend*, *display* or *smear*)

[image: spread translation here]

The most interesting part is that, as you know, the infinitive of a verb in Spanish ends with either -ar, -er or -ir, and that's it. Why then "extender**se**" or "difundir**se**"?

Well if we look more carefully at the definition provided by wordreference (or any other decent dictionary), we notice a small "**prnl**" near the verb. That means it is a **pronominal verb**.

> The defining characteristic of pronominal verbs is that their subjects are acting upon themselves
>
> <sub>More about [pronominal verbs](http://www.elearnspanishlanguage.com/grammar/verb/pronominalverbs.html)</sub>

So pronominal verbs must be conjugated with a reflexive pronoun, like `se`.

It is trickier than that, because you see in the examples:

> Los animales infectados **propagan** la enfermedad por todo el país.

`Propagate` is not *pronominal*, but is a transitive verb (A transitive verb is a verb that can take a *direct object*. In other words, it is done to someone or something. In some cases the agent is the one that receives the action). In your case it is the illness what spreads "itself" all over someone's body. That is why it has that reflexive meaning. Thus, you need to say

> La enfermedad (o el veneno) **se propagó** por todo su cuerpo.

You can recognize pronominal verbs by the reflexive pronoun `se` tacked on to the infinitive: *ducharse, ponerse, lavarse, quedarse*, etc. I showed a couple uses of *propagar*, with and without the `se`. I hope this doesn't add confusion. There is a lot that can be said about pronominal verbs but I just wanted to highlight why you would need to use it in this case, to refer to the poison spreading.

Answer (score 4):

Spanish is a idiom that have a lot of synonyms so you can use **se (propagó/difundió/diseminó/extendió/esparció)** all these will be well with you phrase.

> El veneno se (propagó/difundió/diseminó/extendió/esparció) por todo su cuerpo

Maybe you are thinking why use **se** before the verb **(se extendió)**. This word in this case is a reflexive pronoun This meaning that the word suggest the action is do itself.

Comment: Daniel, aunque tu respuesta es correcta, posiblemente la parte que más dificultad da a quienes están aprendiendo español y la que merece más explicación es el uso del se. Una buena respuesta explicaría el uso de ese pronombre en la frase.